# Android x86 Prelink

Tags: android

Please throw some light on How the prelinking or preloading is handled in Android-x86 platform. Because, I am seeing only prelink-linux-arm.map in the code. The x86 loader is also using the same filename? If so, Is the loading address in the map file is same for both x86 and ARM platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the latest (30/08/2010) discussion, I understood that, Android-x86 project is NOT using the pre-linking feature.